# R quadratic multi dimensional optimization with constraints

Tags: r, constraints, quadratic, nonlinear-optimization

I am tryinig to solve the quadratic optimization of the following function:

```
b<-4.7e-09
a<-(-2e-05)
M<-100
beta<-0.5
min<-fuction(x){
    x1=x[1]
    x2=x[2]
    x3=x[3]
    E=a*x1+b*x1^2+a*x2+b*x2^2+a*x3+b*x3^2
    V=(M-x1)+(M-x1-x2)+(M-x1-x2-x3)
    return (E+beta*V)
}
```

And the constrains are

```
x1+x2+x3=M
x1>=0,x2>=0,x3>=0
```

Is there a way I can solve this problem using constrOptim or solve.QP?

Not necessarily, but integral optimization would be better.

I appreciate any comment.

Comment: Have a look at the `nloptr` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Note: In what follows I call your function `f(...)` to avoid confusion with the built-in R function `min(...)`. Also, I'm assuming that `x2=x[3]` in your code is an error, and you want `x2=x[2]`.]

First, before you resort to numerical optimization, you should do some basic math. If x<sub>i</sub> ≥ 0 and `sum(x) = M`, then x<sub>i</sub> ≤ M. So we are operating in a cube with sides (0,M). Further, if `sum(x) = M` then we really have only 2 independent variables (say x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub>) and x<sub>3</sub> = M - (x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub>). We can determine the minimum relatively easily this way:

```
x    <- seq(0,M,len=101)
df   <- expand.grid(x=x,y=x)
df$f <- mapply(function(x,y) f(c(x,y,M-(x+y))),df$x,df$y)
df$f <- ifelse(df$x+df$y>M,NA,df$f)
df[which.min(df$f),]
#       x y         f
# 101 100 0 -0.001953
```

So the minimum of f occurs at x<sub>1</sub>=M, x<sub>2</sub> = x<sub>3</sub> = 0.

Since the function `f(...)`, is a surface, we can plot this to confirm, as follows (it is always a good idea to plot the function if at all possible!!).

```
library(reshape2)     # for dcast(...)
library(rgl)          # for surface3d(...), etc.
z       <- dcast(df,x~y,value.var="f")[-1]
zlim    <- range(z[!is.na(zz)])
palette <- rev(heat.colors(10))
col     <- palette[9*(df$f-zlim[1])/diff(zlim) + 1] 
surface3d(x,x,as.matrix(zz),color=col)
axes3d()
title3d(xlab="X",ylab="Y",zlab="Z")
```

[image]

So the surface turns out to be a plane, and the minimum is indeed at (100,0,0).

Finally, we can of course use a numerical optimizer (which IMO is overkill for this problem - unless of course this is a homework assignment??). Here we use `nloptr(...)` from the package of the same name. `f(...)` is the function to be minimized, `g(...)` is the constraint expressed as an inequality, `abs(sum(x)-M) <= 0`. and `lb` is a vector of the lower bounds on `x`. You can also specify the constraint as an equality using `eval_g_eq=...`. Read the documentation for more details.

```
f <-function(x){                   # objective function
  x1=x[1]
  x2=x[2]
  x3=x[3]
  E=a*x1+b*x1^2+a*x2+b*x2^2+a*x3+b*x3^2
  V=(M-x1)+(M-x1-x2)+(M-x1-x2-x3)
  return (E+beta*V)
}
g <- function(x) {abs(sum(x)-M)}   # constraint function

library(nloptr)
result <-nloptr(c(0,0,0), f, lb=c(0,0,0), eval_g_ineq=g,
                opts = list(algorithm="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA"))
result$solution
# [1] 1.000000e+02 4.440892e-16 4.835780e-16
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It should be **x2=x[2]** and sorry for the typo. I tried this on my computer, the only problem is when using `nloptr` the optimal value is `100, 0, 2.220446e-16`. The summation is bigger than M.

Comment: It isn't. This is rounding error: 2.2e-16 is essentially 0.

Comment: I have just run the above code and it returned the following error to me: `Error in a * x1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator.` at the `result <-nloptr(c(0,0,0), f, lb=c(0,0,0), eval_g_ineq=g, opts = list(algorithm="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA"))` line.